# Insert array to to single MySQL raw with foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I need to insert MySQL data from array values to a single raw. I have tried code below but I am getting error: Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in
How can I solve this problem? Or is there any alternative way to insert array values to single raw in MySQL using PHP?

```
<?php

foreach ($_POST['qty'] as $product_id => $qty) {
$product_id = implode(" ",$product_id);
$qty = implode(" ",$qty);
}
$q = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO product_order (product_id,qty) VALUES ('$product_id','$qty')");

?>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to save comma separated values in the db?

Comment: Yes. Right.....

Comment: please don't do that. It's a bad idea. You will find thousands of questions here from people who did that and struggled there after.

Comment: liakat.skype this is my skype. plz add me. i want to show u my database structure. i am not getting idea to save it to database without comma

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post array to database then use php serialize function.It is best for array type data

```
    $serialized_data = serialize(array('Math', 'Language', 'Science'));  
echo  $serialized_data . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Implode function second parameters accept Array so at first check in implode function the second parameter is array.

```
foreach ($_POST['qty'] as $product_id => $qty)
```

This line says `$product_id` is key which is not array so implode function should not work.

Please provide `$_POST['qty']` dump

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
 $product = [];
 $qtys = [];
if(!empty($_POST['qty'])){
foreach ($_POST['qty'] as $product_id => $qty) {
   array_push($product, $product_id);
   array_push($qtys, $qty);
}
 $qty_final = implode(',',$qtys);
 $product_id_final = implode(',',$product);
 $q = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO product_order (product_id,qty) VALUES ('$product_id_final','$qty_final')");
}
```

It is very bad idea to save comma separated values in db.

Comment: i dont want save with comma but i am not getting idea to manage the order thats why doing like that. can i have ur skype? i can share you my sql tables picture there

Comment: @KevinHeimlich Have you tried my above method. Did it work for you? For without comma you need to create another table and store the ids accordingly.

Comment: yes. can i get ur skype id? i want show u something...plz help

Comment: @KevinHeimlich Whatever you want to show, you can attach it to the question.

Comment: attached my table screen shot. check there product i have s single raw. how can i save multiple products id there?

Comment: @KevinHeimlich Create a third table. And store the product id and qty in that table and link it with the orderid. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could do,

```
<?php
$product_data = isset(($_POST['qty'])? ($_POST['qty']: array();
if ( !empty($product_data) ){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO product_order (product_id, qty) VALUES ('".implode(", ", array_keys($product_data))."','".implode(", ", array_values($product_data))."')";
    $q = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
?>
```

This should work.

But keeping comma seperated list in a field is not a good thing to do. You could have a new table, so that you can keep a mapping to what products are in what order.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a good idea.** - It is a very bad idea.

That being said. Your `$product_id` is not an array - it is an array key (`string` or `integer`) so there is nothing to implode.

Instead of inserting csv into this table it would be a much better idea to insert new row for each id you have.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?php

$product_data = isset(($_POST['qty'])? ($_POST['qty']: array();

if ( !empty($product_data) ){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO product_order (product_id, qty) VALUES ('".implode(", ", array_keys($product_data))."','".implode(", ", array_values($product_data))."')";

    $q = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

}
?>
```